# XMPP Getting/Sending Full JID Without Subscribing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm currently developing a small chat application using iOS and XMPPFramework.

I registered two users on a XMPP client on a public XMPP server.

However, when I send messages to the bare JIDs via my iOS app, users connected on the app would not receive the message because the XMPP client had sent a presence with a higher priority.

To fix that, I just have the users send their presence with the highest priority, so that when I send a message to their bare JID, the messages are routed to the proper resource. However, I feel like this is not a good way to go about it. I would like to send the message directly to the full JID, but I'm not sure how to get it.

What is the proper way to send or receive the full JID of a user without subscribing? Is it possible or is it just bad practice? Am I supposed to send it in the presence?

Comment: i have same similar question.I am trying to send the friend req i.e subscribe the user when opposite user in offline and send message to them

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate.h
`+ (AppDelegate*)instance;`

AppDelegate.m
`+ (AppDelegate*)instance {
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}`

Then in your ViewController.m
`XMPPJID *myJID = [[AppDelegate instance] xmppStream].myJID;`

This will give you the full JID. Hope this is what you asked.. let me know if not or anything else regarding this.

Comment: it return me    20515@myserver/d825a3afw  how can i remove the value after "/-----"

Comment: You can use .myJID.user to access the value before "/"